# Finding php files that have numbers in the filename

Tags: linux, php, find, ls

Can someone help me with a command line to find all .php files on a server with a number in the filename?

I have searched, as best I can, for other answers, but they typically show for a specific file name structure (such as c[0-9][4-7]_list.txt), my need is ANY filename with a number in it and a .php extension, for example:

push1.php
23test.php
up22date.php

Would all be valid for my search purposes.

Reasons for wanting: hacked Wordpress install, where I am finding multiple files added to directories with this kind of structure. I am auditing all files, but I feel starting with these most likely candidates are my priority (along with password changes, obviously).

Many thanks for any help given, or a slap and pointed to another answer already given would also be appreciated :-)

Comment: Have you looked at the date the files were created - I generally find that when cleaning a hacked WP install that the date of files is a dead giveaway.

Comment: Appreciated input, I'm doing that now.

Comment: Turned out that, having a purchased theme that doesn't update automagically, there was a massive security hole in the theme that made everything else I was doing pointless - 12 hours of battling the spamming *rude words here*. Correct notifications of theme updates added and a rather red face for having let it happen in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find` to locate files - using the numeric character set `[0-9]` to match files with a number, and suffix .php

```
find . -name \*[0-9]\*.php
```

Comment: Glad it helped. BTW you don't know - but  it is customary to accept the answer that works for you and upvote answers that you approve of (when you have reputation to upvote).

Comment: I did upvote, but have since realised, and now had confirmed by you, that I don't yet have enough reputation to make that show on the site. I will, of course, do that again when I've got the reputation to do so. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

find . -name '*[0-9]*.php'

Should find any file with a number in it.

Comment: Code formatting appears to be wrong in your post. I presume you meant to say `find . -name '*[0-9]*.php'` but the markdown is wrong.